# Which search algorithm does google maps use to find paths and why?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, search

I am curious about it as somewhere I heard it is breadth first search but A* search is more faster than BFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google would use either A* or BFS. They probably have some of their own proprietary algorithms. If you're looking for similar algorithms, I would look into [Dijskstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) or because roads are almost planar graphs [Fastest Shortest-Path For Planar Graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000097914938).

Answer (score 1):

Google always has something mysterious in its pocket. The best possible option among all the known option is Dijskstra's because of the planar graph solution, but as I said in first line that it alone could not be enough for such complex system there should be some supportive algorithms along with Dijskstra's. the another example that satisfies my answer is that google core algorithm also use some supportive algo like penguin,panda,KBT algo etc..